# Laravel + VueJs not display in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, internet-explorer, babel-polyfill

I've used Laravel and Vuejs in my project and it works well in all browsers but  it's a problem in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was solved in this way (Note I use `Laravel-Mix` and my Laravel version is 5.8)

1. Install

   ```
   npm install whatwg-fetch --save
   npm install --save babel-polyfill

   npm run dev
   ```
2. then edit your `app.js`. (its default in `resources/assets/js/app.js`)

   ```
   // resources/assets/js/app.js

   import "babel-polyfill";
   import 'whatwg-fetch';

   require('./bootstrap');
   ...
   ```

resource: [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/laravel-vue-recommandations-about-using-polyfill-for-internet-explorer)